# Magento swatch is not disabled when configurable product is not on stock

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, swatches, out-of-stock, configurable-swatches

I have a little problem at my Magento 2.2.5 store. When a combination of a configurable product is not on stock, the swatch should be disabled with a red strike. But at my store no swatch is disabled, as you can see at the following screenshot:

[image: No disabled Swatch]

Actually, the Large size and green color isn't on stock. So it should be:

[image: What is should be]

Is somebody know what to do? If i want to select this combination and put it in my cart, i get the error "not on stock"

Comment: hi @Kees, This is not the default behavior of magento 2, Need to customize to achieve that functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by installing the following module:

https://github.com/mjankiewicz/MagentoConfigurableProduct

Comment: your link is not working, can you please share other working link

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not, because i found this solution 1 year ago... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try indexing :

- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Yes, i get an error:

Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log.
Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log.

Comment: Can you share the error? Also, you can try php bin/magento setup:di:compile to get the exact error.

Comment: Error is too long, i made a screenshot: https://ibb.co/L6c5YVW

Comment: Compilation result: 
Compilation was started.
Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 21 secs 260.0 MiB
Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.

Comment: Check if Admin>Store>Catalog>Catalog>Use Flat Catalog Category & make it NO

Comment: It's already set to no!

Comment: Then Flash magento Cache by php bin/magento cache:flush
Backup DB
Then you should drop table catalog_category_flat_store_1, if it is exit in db by

Next enable Catalog Flat for Category by Use Flat Catalog Category make it yes

Final,you need to indexing from magento cli : php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: It's not working unfortunately. I get the same error: Catalog rule indexing failed

Comment: Okay one more thing: can you query SELECT * FROM `setup_module` WHERE `module` LIKE 'Magento_Catalog'

Comment: Hmm hold on. I missed a step in your previous possible solution. I don't have access to my DB right now. Only SSH and sFTP. I will contact my hoster for DB access and will come back to you soon :-)

Comment: @KeesJanssen once you have DB access try to query SELECT * FROM setup_module WHERE module LIKE 'Magento_Catalog'. You should leave previous steps for now. Actually you have some problem with database, this happens because of incomplete indexing.

Comment: Allright, thanks for your help so far. I will let you know!

Comment: Hi Imran,

I'm seeing this: https://ibb.co/KVgv46k. My version is 2.2.5. Is this the error? Should i change the DB cells to 2.2.5 instead of 2.2.3?

EDIT: Tried it, unfortunately not any success

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Magento_Catalog should be 2.2.5 & Please try to run these command: 1. composer update  2. bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I now get the following error:

main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 100000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes.

Comment: Hello Imran, Did you get the message before? Hope you can help me out with this :-)

Comment: Hi, Kees Janssen. Sorry I was busy on some project. If possible you can add me on Skype, so that we can get this thing fixed :) my skype is: imibrohi